# how to parsing 10 digit number text into integer in java

Tags: java

I have set `"phone"` as `int` of 10 digit in database and take input as text which I parse using

```
String phone1=request.getParameter("phone");

int phone =Integer.parseInt(phone1);
```

but it does not work why?

Comment: What the exact error that you faced?

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the content of the string? Note that phone numbers could start with a + if the contain the country code or contain other characters like spaces or minues, e.g. `301-555-42`. And what about reconstructing the string? Leading zeros would be stripped.

Comment: Please define `does not work`

Comment: Have your "10 digits" blank spaces for example `12 3456 7890`?

Comment: not all 10-digit numbers can fit in an integer.

Comment: Phone numbers should remain as Strings not integers, there are way more unnecessary problems if you want phone numbers as integers.

Answer (score 6):

In Java you can store in `int` variable numbers in range -2147483648 to 2147483647. This is not enough for your 10-digit telephone numbers. You can easily fix this using `long`:

```
long phone = Long.parseLong(phone1);
```

On the other hand I would rethink using number data types for storing telephone numbers. Why?

- Because you can't store leading zeros if your numbers are not always exact 10 digits long.
- Because you loose formating, like "123-456-..."
- Because you can't save things like `#` or `p`, that are valid and used sometimes in phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is in format sth like (+3212-45-356) or sth else. Before you parse it you have to make that string clean from that 'special characters'. Try parsing it to long.

```
String phone1=request.getParameter("phone");

Long phone =Integer.parseLong(phone1.replace("\\+","").replace.("-",""));
```

Answer (score -1):

One problem is, that a preceding 0 will make the number, octal, in base 8; and then digits 8 and 9 cause a NumberFormatException. Base 8 allows to represent 3 bits 0-1 with one digit 0-7.

```
long phone = Long.parseLong(phone1, 10);
```

This forces base 10.

Of course, as one does not calculate with phone numbers, and by this conversion looses preceding zeroes, this might be less suited. In many countries international numbers are entered with either preceding `+` or `00`.

Comment: Looking into JDK sources: `int parseInt(String s) {return parseInt(s,10);}`

Comment: @BorisBrodski: you are right, I now remember that Sun changed it; no longer default octal when with 0.